# Running Code Just Once

Tags: c#, thread-safety, asynchronous

I want a code run just once (say in `Dispose`). `WriteOnceBlock<T>` from TPL Data Flow could be used here; but again if we need to *check* if it is done (in a 'not data flow' friendly manner), we have to call `Receive` and timeout and things.

I wrote this and it works, but I am not sure about when comparison takes place (`==`); is it possible for that to be rearranged so something goes wrong and out of time/order?

```
public class Once
{
    const Int32 JobDone = 11011;
    const Int32 NotDone = 119;

    Int32 _done;

    public Once() { _done = NotDone; }

    public bool IsDone() { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _done, JobDone, NotDone) == JobDone; }
}
```

And usage:

```
readonly Once _stopped = new Once();
public void OnStop()
{
    if (_stopped.IsDone()) return;

    //...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this might work for your scenario, but you might want to look at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Are you looking for behavior like C++11's `call_once`?  In addition to doing an operation only once, it also guarantees that the operation will have been completed before it returns (even if that means blocking for another thread which is doing the op), and it synchronizes with that thread.  Doing all of those extra steps takes more work than just the things you asked for.

Comment: What you've referred to here is achievable exactly with `WriteOnceBlock<T>` - as I've mentioned at the first line - or `Lazy<T>` as @TopinFrassi suggested. Both are too much of a ceremony for just ensuring a method is already called or not. You are right about ensuring if the action is completed, which again can be done using a simple `Task` and continue in case of fault and such. But there are situations that this class would suffice; it is thread-safe and non-blocking.

Comment: [What you can / can't do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c/1765#1765)

Comment: You could implement IDisposable so that when the object is disposed you throw an Exception if it get calls after disposed, this ensure the the object can't be reuse.

Comment: Thanks, but throwing exceptions is not a high performance computation and IMHO should not be used to control the flow; but for identifying exception cases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few items to make this code better.

1. Naming. Once is an OK name for the class, but the method name `IsDone` is a problem. This is an 'atomic' operation that sets values, as well as gets values. A method called something like "Trigger", and changing the class name to a common term like `OneShot`, will give you the semantics like:

   ```
   private readonly OneShot terminator = new OneShot();


   if (terminator.Trigger())
   {
       ... do something if we are the first trigger
   }
   ```

   or, using your semantics, the negated value:

   ```
   if (!terminator.Trigger()) return;
   ```
2. Your fields should all be private.

   ```
   private const Int32 JobDone = 11011;
   private const Int32 NotDone = 119;

   private Int32 _done;
   ```

   otherwise other code can possibly reset or mess up your trigger.
3. Why use the bizarre numbers for the constants? What's wrong with 1, and 0. The special numbers make me think there's something especially magical with them.

Apart from that, the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` is the right tool for the job. It creates an atomic compare-and-set operation that makes it thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for great answer! Still I like `IsDone` better, it is read so to me! And fields are all private; that's the default member access in C#.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian `IsDone` implies that the method checks whether it is done, it doesn't say that is also changes the state to done. I would be confused by that.

Comment: @svick You are right. But here is another problem: we need again to call the sequence of methods like `if !IsDone then SetDone; if IsDone then return`; the 2 step verification. I agree that `IsDone` is a bad name for my method. But it removes the need for a two step verification. What should it be called?

Answer (score 5):

**Spacing**

Single-line methods, while possible, are pretty much universally a bad idea. It costs nothing to split them over a few lines, and you gain tons in readability.

```
public bool IsDone() { return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _done, JobDone, NotDone) == JobDone; }
```

looks better as:

```
public bool IsDone() 
{ 
    return Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _done, JobDone, NotDone) == JobDone;
}
```

It is similarly recommended (and a StyleCop violation) that you put conditional clauses in brackets, so:

```
if (_stopped.IsDone()) return;
```

Should be:

```
if (_stopped.IsDone())
{
    return;
}
```

However for something as short as `return;` I'd be happy to let it slide.

**Types**

Why are you using `Int32` when `int` works just as well?